# Send IRP read/write packets from UMDF driver to kernel-mode driver

Tags: windows, driver, umdf, irp

Is it possible to create and send IRP read/write packets from UMDF driver to kernel-mode driver that represents the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible via calling FormatRequestForRead/FormatRequestForWrite method of IO target and sending request. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559236(v=vs.85).aspx for example.